# Assert that mapDispatchToProps function has been called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, redux-mock-store

I am attempting to test that I am calling one of my `mapDispatchToProps` functions with args, however I can't seem to get it to work...

I attempted to follow [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525117/how-can-i-test-the-mapdispatchtoprops-with-react-testing-library), but it didn't seem to work for me.

**Component.jsx**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    myFunction: (data) => dispatch(myAction(data))
});

const Component = ({buttonText, myFunction}) => (
    <button data-testid="test" onClick={() => myFunction(123)}>{buttonText}</button>
)

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const myAction = agentData => ({
    type: `MY_ACTION`, 
    agentData
});
```

**Test.js**

```
import createMockStore from "redux-mock-store";

it('Should pass', () => {
    const mockStore = createMockStore();
    const store = mockStore({});

    const mockUpdate = jest.fn(data => console.log('HIT FUNCTION with ' + data));
    const props = {buttonText: 'Click me', myFunction: mockUpdate};

    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...props}/>
        </Provider>
    );

    userEvent.click(screen.queryByTestId('test'));

    expect(mockUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
});
```

I have also tried moving the `myFunction: mockUpdate` from the `props` object into the `mockStore({})` initial object, but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Your mock `myFunction` didn't invoke when you click the button. Because the returned value of `mapDispatchToProps` will become the props of the component.

You can get the mock `myFunction` via the second parameter of `mapDispatchToProps` function named `ownProps`. You may want to call the mock `myFunction` when dispatching the action. If so, `expect(mockUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();` assertion will work.

`component.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { myAction } from './actions';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  console.log('Your mock myFunction is here:', ownProps.myFunction);
  // But below myFunction is not a mock function and is passed into your component finally.
  return {
    myFunction: (data) => dispatch(myAction(data)),
  };
};

const Component = ({ buttonText, myFunction }) => (
  <button data-testid="test" onClick={() => myFunction(123)}>
    {buttonText}
  </button>
);

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Component from './component';

it('Should pass', async () => {
  const mockStore = createMockStore();
  const store = mockStore();

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component buttonText="Click me" />
    </Provider>
  );

  await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('test'));
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: 'MY_ACTION', agentData: 123 }]);
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75173986/component.test.tsx (8.625 s)
  ✓ Should pass (92 ms)

  console.log
    Your mock myFunction is here: [Function: mockConstructor] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
    }

      at Function.mapDispatchToProps [as mapToProps] (stackoverflow/75173986/component.tsx:6:11)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 actions.ts    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 component.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.103 s, estimated 10 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution! How would I go about including `mapStateToProps` in here also? Do I include within the `mockStore`? Something like `const store = mockStore({mapState1: 'some value'});`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by combining something similar to @Lin Du and also some other resources I found online (that I can't seem to find in my search history to link to at the moment).

This solution doesn't require any additional args such as testProps to be added to the `mapDispatchToProps` function.

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

...

it('Should call next step with both call plan and caller display', () => {
    const store = { /* any mapStateToProps data here */ };
    const mockStore = configureStore()(store);
    mockStore.dispatch = jest.fn(); // Can add callback in here to update the non-mock store

    const props = {buttonText: 'Click me'};

    provider = getComponentProvider(ChooseCallPlan, store, {wizard}, true);
    render(
        <Provider store={mockStore}>
           <Component {...props}/>
        </Provider>
    );

    userEvent.click(screen.queryByTestId('test'));

    export(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockStore.dispatch)
        .toHaveBeenCalledWith(myAction(123));
});
```